# Need to find out the execution time of all the views and stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am wondering if we have anything in place in the oracle database which will give me the execution time of all the views and stored procedures.

For views - When I am executing manually using select * from view; this is fetching the results from the cache memory and giving the execution time which is less. But originally the views were taking more than 4secs to give the results. So, I need to find out the execution time of all views and stored procedures. Is there any way to find out these details as this is required for performance tuning purposes?

Database version: Oracle SQL Developer (19c)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may try to examine [AWR](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgdba/gathering-database-statistics.html#GUID-26D359FA-F809-4444-907C-B5AFECD9AE29) history to check execution times of statements involving these views. You cannot obtain a pure *view execution* time just because such entity doesn't exists: 1) if the view is used in some SQL statement, then it will most likely be merged with an outer query (and possibly resulting in entirely different execution plan)

Comment: and 2) row source doen't produce all the rows in a batch, but provides new rows to the consumer when it is ready to consume them (for example, hashing will be a sync point because Oracle have to build a hashtable before it may send something downstream, while NL join may send a row when it has finished a lookup for it). So overall performance depends on the entire query, not some (logically isolated) part of it (because a general view is not much different from a subquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle SQL Developer is *not* a database, it is a client application. Oracle 19c is a database.

In SQL Developer, the execution time of a query from a worksheet is visible in the SQL History pane. Real-time monitoring of top SQL performance across the database instance can be done using the Instance Viewer from the DBA tools. Tuning of individual SQL statements can be done with the SQL Tuning Advisor in SQL Developer.

For deeper level performance tuning, the AWR Report (available in the DBA tools in SQL Developer, and which requires licensing of the Diagnostics Pack) will have execution statistics of poorly performing SQL, as well as recommendations for tuning at the system level.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Panorama](https://github.com/rammpeter/Panorama) you can get execution and runtime statistics for executed SQLs.
Without licensing of Diagnostics Pack only based on the current SQLs held in SGA memory, otherwise also back in time from AWR history.